# Unable to set foreign key SQLite.swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am not able to set foreign key using stephencelis SQLite.swift.

```
t.foreignKey(user_id, references:"user_mstr",user_id)
```

I have two tables `user_master` and `user_details`. How to set `user_id` as a foreign key in `user_detail` table. I am getting  below error.

```
Cannot invoke foreignkey with an arguement list of type (Expression<string>),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing string to references. It should be like

```
let user_id = Expression<String>("user_id")

let user_mstr = Table("user_mstr")

//cate t somehow

t.foreignKey(user_id, references: user_mstr, user_id)
```